# Mysql Shell dump Script not working

Tags: bash, shell, mysql

Hey i have a problem in my shell script that i can't handle and that's why i need your help.

So this is my Script:

```
MYSQL_DUMP=/usr/bin/mysqldump
BACKUP_DIR=/backup/mysql
TAR=/bin/tar
RM=/bin/rm
DB_NAME=Homepage
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=liron3211
AKT_DATUM=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`


$MYSQL_DUMP $DB_NAME -u $DB_USER --password=$DB_PASS > \
$BACKUP_DIR/$AKT_DATUM.backup.sql


cd $BACKUP_DIR
$TAR -cvzf $AKT_DATUM.backup.sql.tgz $AKT_DATUM.backup.sql


$RM $AKT_DATUM.backup.sql
```

So i want that the Script creates a sql file of my Database "Homepage" and to put it in the folder /backup/mysql and how can i transfer it from my root Server to another ftp Server?

EDIT: This is my Error:

```
./backup.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

Would be awesome if u can help me :)

Best Regards 
oRxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will upload it trought ssh, use scp:

`scp <file to upload> <username>@<hostname>:<destination path>`

add to your file at the bottom:
note that you should have passwordless connection to the host!

`scp $BACKUP_DIR/$AKT_DATUM.backup.sql.tgz user@server1:/my/mysql/backups`

This way is much more secure. But if you use ftp, You can use a [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to do this e.g.

```
ftp -n $FTP_SERVER <<End-Of-Session
# -n option disables auto-logon

user anonymous "$FTP_PASS"
binary
cd $FTP_DIR
put "$AKT_DATUM.backup.sql.tgz"
bye
End-Of-Session
```

- Don't forget to add the variables in the beginning of your script:

  ```
   FTP_PASS=password1
   FTP_SERVER=my.ftp.server
   FTP_DIR=/remote/dir/
  ```

Comment: Allright i edited my Script like this:

$TAR -cvzf /backup/$AKT_DATUM.backup.tgz /backup/ 
And
put "/backup/$AKT_DATUM.backup.tgz"

But he put its now on the Ftp server but after tar he is giving me that command and after he is done uploading my file get deleted on my ftp


/bin/tar: /backup/201504081645.backup.tgz: file changed as we read it
?Invalid command

Comment: This is why because you are archiving the directory /backup/ where your file /backup/$AKT_DATUM.backup.tgz is located and this cannot happen, because you add the same file to your archive, like recursive.

Keep the full command:
`$TAR -cvzf $AKT_DATUM.backup.sql.tgz $AKT_DATUM.backup.sql`
After that you need to upload the same file on the ftp. Use ssh instead, it's more secure and easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
./backup.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

This error is because you have an unexpected line break.  You need to either put the file you are redirecting stdout to on the same line or use a backslash to signify a line continuation:

```
$MYSQL_DUMP $DB_NAME -u $DB_USER --password=$DB_PASS > \
$BACKUP_DIR/$AKT_DATUM.backup.sql
```